# Not able to get the title of of frame using ng-bind

Tags: spock, geb

I am working on Geb Spock framework for AngularJS application. When I am trying to get the title of framework its returning the value as null. For more details please refer the below html code for it.

```
<modal-header class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" ng-show="zaakAanmakenView.indicatieIntake" cancel="cancel" titel="intake.aanmaken.header">
<div class="modal-header mb5" style="cursor: pointer;">
<h2 class="modal-title">
<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="modalHeader.titel | translate">Create new intake</span>
<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="modalHeader.titel2"></span>
</h2>
<span class="close-popup" ng-click="modalHeader.cancel()">X</span>
</div>
</modal-header>
```

I tried below thing:

```
 intakeScreenTitle(wait:true){$("span", "ng-bind": contains("modalHeader.titel | translate"))}

 intakeScreenTitle.text()
```

Can you please help me to get the title as "Create new intake".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried with

```
intakeScreenTitle(wait:true){$("span", "ng-bind": "modalHeader.titel | translate")}
```

May be there is another span which contains the same ng-bind.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the same as well. But still it is giving the value as null. :(. Can you please help